# Show difference in days in Date::Manip::Delta_Format

Tags: perl, date

I'm calculating the difference between 2 dates what are a few days apart, but the result I get  from Delta_Format shows the days in hours.

```
print Delta_Format(DateCalc(ParseDate("2014-03-07 14:16:23"), ParseDate("2014-03-03 18:43:10")), 0, ("%Mv", "%dv", "%hv", "%mv", "%sv")) . "!\n";
```

Gives me this output:

```
0 0 -91 -33 -13!
```

Which means zero months, zero days, 91 hours, 33 minutes, 13 seconds. How do I make Delta_Format show me 3 days, 19 hours, 33 minutes, 13 seconds?

Comment: `Date::Manip` is an extraordinary module, and covers pretty much everything that you could ever need to do with dates. But it weighs in at nearly 10 megabytes - nearly twice the size of the perl interpreter and compiler together. It can be invaluable for processing and converting between various manual sources, but if all you need to do is compare well-behaved date strings then you should be using the core `Time::Piece` instead.

Comment: In this case I don't care so much about that, it's not production code or anything. :-) But thanks for pointing it out, it's useful for other people who may end up here...

Comment: You will also have found that, because of the sheer size of the module, the documentation is necessarily long and complex. You had to post to Stack Overflow to get it to work! I am sure that, unless you dispose of your programs pretty quickly, you will look at your code again in a few days and wonder about why you used such a big and awkward hammer for what is barely a nut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're trying to normalize your [Date::Manip::Delta](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Date%3A%3AManip%3A%3ADelta&mode=all).  You can specify different modes to DateCalc function in the 4th parameter, and the mode=1 is normalize.  Unfortunately, the way it's implemented allows for negative values, and I'm not sure how to force just positives.  This is one reason why I've never used this module in any serious way :)

```
use Date::Manip;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $date1 = ParseDate("2014-03-07 14:16:23");
my $date2 = ParseDate("2014-03-03 18:43:10");

my $delta = DateCalc($date2,$date1, \my $err, 1);

print Delta_Format($delta, "%Mv %dv %hv %mv %sv"); # 0 4 -4 -26 -47
```

One alternative using Time::Piece

```
use Time::Piece;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $tp1 = Time::Piece->strptime("2014-03-07 14:16:23", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
my $tp2 = Time::Piece->strptime("2014-03-03 18:43:10", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

my $diff = $tp1 - $tp2;

print $diff->pretty, "\n";  #3 days, 19 hours, 33 minutes, 13 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks, Miller, but you just separated the instructions in my code. The only change you made was remove the 2nd parameter on Delta_Format, the rest is exactly the same. I still get the same output.

Comment: I was originally trying to find a way of pretty-printing with Date::Manip. The Time::Piece code do exactly what I wanted originally. Thanks. I will give it some time to see if someone (you? hehe) finds out how to normalize the Delta, otherwise I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks for finding that. After you posted I checked the documentation (which is extremely long and awful to find things), mode 1 is not normalize, it's "approximate". But it worked. It's lame, though, that it shows +4 days, -4 hours; and if you swap the dates it shows -4 days, +4 hours. But nothing anyone can do about, it's surely a bug, documentation reads: 'When a delta is returned, the signs such that it is strictly positive or strictly negative ("1 day -2 hours" would never be returned for example).' Many thanks again. :)

Comment: @Miller: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` in everything that you write, especially in answers on Stack Overflow where thousands of people will be referring to your answers as reference documents

Comment: Please don't use `Date::Manip`, for exactly the reasons that you've found

Comment: @Borodin your first comment here kind of doesn't make sense, since Miller actually was already using the strict/warning directives... :S

Comment: @msb: Thank you. I take that back, and have left my comment in place so that your own continues to makes sense. The problem is that `use strict` and `use warnings` belong *immediately* at the top of the file or after any `package` statement. In this case they weren't being applied to the `Date::Manip` or `Time::Piece` modules when they were compiled. That isn't usually a problem, and may be necessary if a module you're including doesn't like the strictures, but people used to reading modern Perl will expect to see the pragma used at the very start of each package.

Comment: @Borodin It's always been my coding style to include pragmas after my use statements to indicate the beginning of code I was taking full responsibility for.  At the time I made this choice (yes, many years ago), there were a couple cpan modules that occasionally threw harmless warnings such as `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.)` that I didn't want filling up my error logs.  Anyway, I'm probably going to continue sticking to my style for now, but will consider your feedback.

Comment: @Miller: It's rare that there could be any warnings raised in modern modules, but in case there are you should disable the relevant warning category (with `no warnings 'xxx'` - that is why `use warnings` superseded `-w` on the command line) in a `BEGIN` block around the relevant `use Module` and chase the author for a fix. Yes you can continue to avoid checking any modules that you include if you wish, but people like me won't recognise your code, and you lay yourself open to others messing with the modules you're using, resulting in bugs that you can't find.

Comment: @Borodin I'm not sure if this is the best place for chatting, but consider this counter argument:  I want everyone to use strict/warnings.  However, it can be a barrier to entry if applying it to an existing codebase before use statements gives warnings for all files.  Instead, putting it after use statements lets someone incrementally add better coding practices to their files, and makes it more likely that a new coder will actually follow this advice that we all give. (hanging in perl hashes if you'd like to chat directly)